# Convert RTF to PDF on a rule into Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I found a link (http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Transformations) that says that i need to create a file named my-transformers-context.xml and put my configurations there to convert RTF to PDF...
There says that some configuration are already configured but this one (RTF to PDF) and some others (DOC to PDF) are not.
By the way i couldn't find how to create this xml with the right configuration to convert the RTF file into a PDF...
Someone already done something like this? or someone know a link that explain how to configure this xml file?

PROBLEM SOLVED!!!!

I don't know if there is a way to say that i've solved the problem... But here it goes the solution...

I saw what Gagravarr said and started looking for configuration of openoffice into alfresco...

There is a file named:

alfresco-global.properties

and there is two variables named:

ooo.exe

and

ooo.enabled

the first one must indicate the path to sopenoffice.exe

and the second one must be equal to true...

ooo.enabled = true

That solve a lot of problema to convert some kind of file to another... like RTF to PDF...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Alfresco should be able to transform a RTF file to a PDF using OpenOffice (direct or JodConverter, depending on if you're on Community or Enterprise)

Assuming you're on a new enough Alfresco, this webscript will tell you what transformations are available from and to RTF:
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/mimetypes?mimetype=application/rtf#application/rtf

If that doesn't show you RTF -> PDF, then you need to look at your open office configuration/setup

Comment: Sorry for long time to answer you back... I've been alocated on another problem and now back to this one hehe... Well, i've looked for your link and the doesn't show the transformation from RTF to PDF... So you said that i need to look at my open office cofiguration/setup... What does it means?

Comment: In order to be able to do various document transformations, Alfresco needs to have a "pet" copy of openoffice to do the work for it. See
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Setting_up_OpenOffice_for_Alfresco for details (the installer normally does this for you, I guess you skipped that bit though)